# A random variable that is invariant under null & alternative hypotheses

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, density-function, frequentist

Suppose a random variable $X$ has probability density function  $f_0$ and $f_1$ under null and alternative hypothesis, respectively.

Is it possible to find another random variable, $g(X)$, which has the same density under null & alternative hypotheses?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Not considering trivial cases such as $g(X)$= uniform [0,1].

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many, especially since you have placed no conditions on g, such as monotonicity, continuity or anything else. And the null and alternates could be very bizarre as well. Suppose that $f_0$ is the normal and $f_1$ is the distribution of the absolute value of a normal. Then take $g$ to be the absolute value function.

Or suppose that $f_0$ and $f_1$ are each symmetric about the same median. $g(X)$ could be a binarizing function whereby $g(x)=0$ if less than the median and $g(x)=1$ if greater than the median. That would collapse null and alternates into the same function as well.